# Unable to use solid-gauge highchart in backboneJS from ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, highcharts

I want to use solid-gauge highchart in my rails app and I am using backbonejs. For using solid-gauge i copied the files highcharts.js, highcharts-more,js , highcharts-3d.js and solid-gauge.js from http://code.highcharts.com/ on to my assets -> javascript -> backbone -> lib directory. When I run the code I get the error as

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

which points to the solid-gauge.js file that is inside the lib directory. Am I missing any dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that the solid-gauge.js and highcharts.js files were different versions and thus causing errors. The problem was solved by updating all the header files to their latest versions.